# Why is the apples not increasing?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I'm trying to make this little game I found and for some reason when I type "Y" on "Would you like to pick an apple?" IT will stay at 1 no matter what I try. Here is my code:

```
import time
global choice
global gold
global apples
apples = 0
gold = 0

def begin():
    apples = 0
    gold = 0
    print ("Let's go!")
    if gold > 99:
        print ("You've won the game!")
        play = input ("Do you want to play again? Please answer Y/N.")
        if play == "Y":
            begin()
        if play == "N":
            print ("Okay, bye then.")
    pick = input ("Do you want to pick an apple Y/N?")
    if pick == "Y":
        print ("You pick an apple")
        apples=apples+1
        apples = 1
        print ("You currently have,",apples," apples")
        begin ()
    if pick == "N":
        sell = input("Do you want to sell your apples Y/N?")
        if sell ==  "Y":
            gold
            apples
            print ("You currently have,",apples,"apples")
            print("You have sold your apples")
            gold=apples*10
            print ("Your gold is now:",gold)
            begin()
            start()

print ("Hello and welcome!")
name = input("What's your name?")
print ("Welcome, "+name+"!")
print ("The goal of this game is to collect apples")
print ("After you have collected these applaes, you sell them.")
choice = input("Do you want to play? Type Y/N.")
if choice == "Y":
    begin()
if choice == "N":
    print ("Okay, bye then.")
```

If anyone could help me with this problem it would be highly appreciated. I am just a beginner so don't be too harsh. Sorry if this problem is obvious, I have only just started.

Answer (score 0):

After the line

apples = apples + 1

you have the line

apples = 1

which resets apples to 1, causing it to display that you only have 1 apple.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of `global` statements at the top level of your code. Those don't do anything. If you're going to use global variables, you need to put the `global` statements inside the function that uses the variables, to tell Python to use the global variable of that name instead of using a local variable.

Try:

```
apples = 0 # don't repeat these lines inside the function
gold = 0   # (unless you want the variables to get reset each time you call it)

def begin():
    global gold # move the global statements inside the function
    global apples

    # ...
```

The `choice` variable doesn't appear to be used in the `begin` function, so you don't need a `global` statement for it.

As Dobellyo noted, you also have some messed up logic in your assignments to `apples` within the function. You need to decide when you want to be incrementing an existing value and when you want to assign a fixed value instead. It usually doesn't make sense to do both, one after the other.